# Angular2 - loopback-sdk-builder - How to set header in api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, loopback

How can I pass the following header information:

**Header:**

```
var headerInfo = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
headerInfo.append('Authorization', token);
```

**Component code:**

```
fetch(cb) {
        this.membersApi.getData()
        .subscribe(result => {            
            console.log(result);
            //this.redirectUser(result);
        },error => {
            console.log(error);           
        }
);
```

**loopback - sdk** created client model (Created by running **npm run build:sdk**) - 
**membersApi:**

```
public getData(): Observable<any> {
    let _method: string = "GET";
    let _url: string = LoopBackConfig.getPath() + "/" + LoopBackConfig.getApiVersion() +
    "/Members/getMobileUsers";
    let _routeParams: any = {};
    let _postBody: any = {};
    let _urlParams: any = {};
    let result = this.request(_method, _url, _routeParams, _urlParams, _postBody);
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I got a solution that, I edited the base.service.ts file in service/core/ folder, but the problem is, I have to do this every time the new build is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
LoopBackConfig.setAuthPrefix(accessToken);
```

may work